# Modulation and demodulation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I modulated two channels using fmmod() method and demodulate that modulated signal using the fmdemod() method. How can we get back those two channels that are modulated? How can we do this?

My code is:

```
Fs = 8000; % Sampling rate of signal
Fc = 3000; % Carrier frequency
t = [0:Fs-1]'/Fs; % Sampling times
s1 = sin(2*pi*300*t)+2*sin(2*pi*600*t); % Channel 1
s2 = sin(2*pi*150*t)+2*sin(2*pi*900*t); % Channel 2
x = [s1,s2]; % Two-channel signal
dev = 50; % Frequency deviation in modulated signal
y = fmmod(x,Fc,Fs,dev); % Modulate both channels.
z = fmdemod(y,Fc,Fs,dev); % Demodulate both channels.
figure(1);
plot(z);
```

What type of value does variable z contain? How do I get back channels from the fmdemod method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure to correctly understand your question, but you can get the channel 1 by doing:

```
x(1:end,1) % or x(1:end,2) for channel 2
```

For the value `z`, you can get the first demodulated channel by doing:

```
z(1:end,1) % or z(1:end,2) for the second demodulated channel
```

Is it what you need?